# iPhone: streaming WMA, MP3 and AAC

Tags: iphone, streaming, mp3, aac, wma

I need to create a simple media player that can stream internet radio stations in WMA, MP3 and AAC formats as part of a bigger app.

I was wondering if someone could please give me some pointers on where to start and how to go about tackling each of these formats? never really handled this topic before..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For audio streaming on the iPhone you'll have to use the AudioQueue framework. This framework has native support for mp3 and aac but is not easy to get started with. There's an open source project by Matt Gallagher that can play mp3 and aac audio streams by using the AudioQueue framework: [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer).

If you also need to play wma audio streams you have to use the open source FFmpeg library. Decoding wma audio streams with the FFmpeg library is not that hard but integration with the AudioQueue framework for playback is not that straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with handling this problem in a web app, you could try having a UIWebView in your app.